# Which are the basic guidelines for using Delphi IntraWeb with Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: delphi, twitter-bootstrap, intraweb

I would like to use the Bootstrap Framework with Delphi's IntraWeb (I'm using XE2)?  The idea is to have the server side logic done by Delphi, while using the nice controls that come with BootStrap?

What would be the basic components "Hello World" application for this configuration?

What would be the high-level approach for a more elaborate application, for example one with a Bootstrap nav component that has its tab contents populated by Delphi?

Is combining IntraWeb and Bootstrap an overkill?  Would I would be better off with an Indy TIdHTTPServer + Bootstrap?

Comment: Do you need advanced IntraWeb features? Indy TIdHTTPServer and Bootstrap work very well together in the [online demos](http://www.habariwebcomponents.de/demo/index.html) for my own web application framework. (A commercial library)

Comment: Did u manage to do it?

Answer (score 2):

It does not have to be difficult to implement Boostrap with Intraweb, you just have to add the Js files in the ContentFiles property of the IWForm, you just have to take in mind you have to write the html for each component you use for BootStrap.

In http://www.codegearguru.com in the Movie #63 - Using jQuery Mobile with IntraWeb - CodeRage 6 Replay

They have explained how to develope the Fishfact demo using jQueryMobile, using the TIWTemplateProcessorHTML component and standard IW components, so it should no be difficult to adapt it for bootstrap.

Here is the link: http://codegearguru.com/video/063/jQueryMobileFishFacts.html

Althought, there have been a new component suite since last year implementing JQuery and jQuery mobile, you should take a loo at http://www.cgdevtools.com,  I'm using them and let me tell it give you IW app a very nice view. AFAIK they are planning to generate a component suite for Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the web-server is concerned, it should provide the necessary files when the client requests them to run bootstrap client-side: [Bootstrap: File Structure](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/getting-started.html#file-structure)

To populate the components (client-side), you'll have to create the server-side logic so it will enter the correct javascript that does so into the HTML of the pages.